# how to Draw a text with orientation, center align ment and wordwrap(VCL C++)?

Tags: c++, canvas, vcl, drawtext

I am trying to draw a text on paint box canvas with orientation = 900, centre alignment and word-wrap the text in Canvas rectangle. Text should look like below image.

[image: Text on canvas should draw like this]

I am using Embarcadero XE5 c++ IDE and I tried like below example, but it isn't working.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::PBoxPaint(TObject *Sender)
{
   TRect R , DrawRect ; 
   unsigned int    DrawFlags = 0;
   TDrawTextParams DrawParams ;        
            
   PBox->Font->Orientation = 900 ;
   PBox->Canvas->Rectangle(PBox->ClientRect) ;
   String S = L"Angualar Text" ;
          R = PBox->ClientRect ;
   InflateRect(R,-2,-2) ;
   DrawRect = R ;

   DrawFlags = DT_END_ELLIPSIS | DT_NOPREFIX | DT_WORDBREAK | DT_EDITCONTROL | DT_CENTER ;
   
   DrawText(PBox->Canvas->Handle, S.c_str() , -1 , &DrawRect, DrawFlags | DT_CALCRECT) ;
   DrawRect.Right = R.Right;

   if (DrawRect.Bottom < R.Bottom)
   {
      OffsetRect( DrawRect, 0, ( R.Bottom - DrawRect.Bottom ) / 2 );
   }
   else
   {
      DrawRect.Bottom = R.Bottom;
   }

   DrawParams.iTabLength    = 0 ;
   DrawParams.iLeftMargin   = 0 ;
   DrawParams.iRightMargin  = 0 ;
   DrawParams.uiLengthDrawn = 0 ; 
   DrawParams.cbSize        = sizeof(DrawParams) ;

   DrawTextEx(PBox->Canvas->Handle,S.c_str(),-1,&DrawRect,DrawFlags,&DrawParams) ;
 }
```

Can any one please help me to draw a text (like above image) on canvas?
Thank you very much.

Comment: All of the Win32 functions return an error flag (with the actual error code available from `GetLastError()`). I don't see you checking any of them.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano: not *ALL* Win32 functions do. In particular, GDI functions, like the ones the OP is using, do not report errors via `GetLastError()`.  Unless a function's documentation specifically states `GetLastError()` is used, you can't assume it is.